# Ansible: SSH Error: unix_listener: too long for Unix domain socket

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

This is a known issue and I found a solution but it's not working for me.

First I had:

```
fatal: [openshift-node-compute-e50xx] => SSH Error: ControlPath too long
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

So I created a `~/.ansible.cfg`. The content of it:

```
[ssh_connection]    
control_path=%(directory)s/%%h‐%%r
```

But after rerunning my ansible I stil have an error about 'too long'.

```
fatal: [openshift-master-32axx] => SSH Error: unix_listener: "/Users/myuser/.ansible/cp/ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com-centos.AAZFTHkT5xXXXXXX" too long for Unix domain socket
    while connecting to 52.xx.xx.xx:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

Why is it still too long?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible : SSH Error: ControlPath too long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516218/ansible-ssh-error-controlpath-too-long)

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate. This one is about solving it in the Ansible configuration while the possible duplicate is about ssh config itself.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The limit is 104 or 108 characters. (I found different statements on the web)

You XXXed out some sensitive information in the error message so it's not clear how long your path actually is.

I guess `%(directory)s` is replaced with the `.ansible` directory in your users folder. Removing that and using directly your user folder would save you 12 characters:

```
control_path=~/%%h‐%%r
```

<sup>Sure, that will spam your home directory with control sockets.</sup>

Depending on the actual length of your username, you could see if you can just create another directory or find a shorter path anywhere. For example, I use `~/.ssh/tmp/%%h_%%r`

Only 3 chars less but it's enough.

Finally if none of that helps, you still could fall back using `/tmp` for storing the sockets. But be aware that anyone with access to `/tmp` on that machine might be able to use your sockets then.

Comment: Also if your host name ist long you can use a Hash with `control_path = %(directory)s/%%C` as [suggested here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11536#issuecomment-153030743).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It worked well.

Answer (score 10):

Just to add more, as the error shows this problem generally happens when the control path is too long for Unix domain socket, hence, to specific to ansible.

You can easily fix this by updating your config file to use the %C format instead of %r@%h:%p as follow:

```
$ mkdir ~/.ssh/control 
$ vim ~/.ssh/config 
Host *
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/control/%C
  ControlMaster auto
```

More Detail: man ssh_config defines the %C format as 'a hash of the concatenation: %l%h%p%r'. And refer [here](https://gist.github.com/andyvanee/bcf95b1044b80e72b4a42933549a079b).

Answer (score 5):

Customizing the `control_path` solves the problem for me. Here is how to do it without spamming the home directory.

The `control_path` defaults to ([documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#control-path)):

```
control_path=%(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r
```

Edit ansible config.

```
vim ~/.ansible.cfg
```

Here are sample file contents with new `control_path` value:

```
[defaults]
inventory=/etc/ansible/hosts

[ssh_connection]
control_path=%(directory)s/%%h-%%r
control_path_dir=~/.ansible/cp
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that doesn't assume I'm an ansible expert (wait...where do I set control_path?  Oh, *THERE!*)

Answer (score 0):

For me, Ansible config file was missing. After that it worked for me.