# Ansible configuration files

Tags: ansible

I'm just starting out with Ansible and I'm having some issues with the configuration file.

Initially, I wasn't being able to ping hosts because my ansible socket path file was too long. I changed this by referring to: [Ansible: SSH Error: unix_listener: too long for Unix domain socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970686/ansible-ssh-error-unix-listener-too-long-for-unix-domain-socket) and changed my path to `control_path=~/%%h‐%%r`.

What are these escape sequences (`%%h and %%r`) for? Is there any documentation available? Is there a way to make my path smaller? Is there an escape sequence for IP address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to Ansible. The control path is where SSH stores its sockets for multiplex sessions.

http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5

> **ControlPath**
>   Specify the path to the control socket used for connection sharing as described in the ControlMaster section above or the string “none” to disable connection sharing. In the path, ‘%L’ will be substituted by the first component of the local host name, ‘%l’ will be substituted by the local host name (including any domain name), ‘%h’ will be substituted by the target host name, ‘%n’ will be substituted by the original target host name specified on the command line, ‘%p’ the destination port, ‘%r’ by the remote login username, ‘%u’ by the username and ‘%i’ by the numeric user ID (uid) of the user running ssh(1), and ‘%C’ by a hash of the concatenation: %l%h%p%r. It is recommended that any ControlPath used for opportunistic connection sharing include at least %h, %p, and %r (or alternatively %C) and be placed in a directory that is not writable by other users. This ensures that shared connections are uniquely identified.

So, there is no placeholder for the hosts IP. Making the path shorter always is a compromise. `~/%%h‐%%r` already is the shortest possible solution that is not unsafe. If you can guarantee you do not ever use another remote user to connect to the host it might be safe to drop `%r` and only use `%h`.

If the problem is that your hostname is too long, maybe creating an alias in your .ssh/config is a solution?

```
host short-name
    hostname very-long-name-that-makes-control-path-location-exceed-the-possible-length-limitation
```

`%n` then should refer to `short-name` which can be used instead of `%h`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `ansible.cfg` file. It may be beside your project or in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

```
[ssh_connection]
control_path = %(directory)s/%%C
```

In new ansible versions no need for this variable.